# Can I have different sections with same place holder in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sublayout

Below is my sublayout called SectionWrapper

```
<section>
    <sc:Placeholder ID="phSectionWrapper" runat="server" Key="phSectionWrapper" />
    <a href="#">check this</a>
</section>
```

I want to achieve is multiple "sections" with different placeholders like

```
<section>
    <caraousal 1 />
    <a href="#">check this</a>
</section>
<section>
    <caraousal 2 />
    <a href="#">check this</a>
</section>
```

But it's now rendering as

```
<section>
    <caraousal 1 />
    <a href="#">check this</a>
    <caraousal 2 />
</section>
<section>
    <a href="#">check this</a>
</section>
```

My presentation details are configured on item as below:

- SectionWrapper (with some placeholder)
- caraousal1 (with placeholder as phSectionWrapper)
- SectionWrapper (with some placeholder)
- caraousal2 (with placeholder as phSectionWrapper)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placeholder keys must be unique on the page. You cannot have 2 placeholders on the same page with the same key - Sitecore will not know in which of them should put the components.

Check Sitecore Dynamic Placeholders - from what I remember there are multiple implementations ready to use, e.g.:

- https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/I/Integrated_Dynamic_Placeholders.aspx
- http://johnnewcombeuk.blogspot.com/2012/06/sitecore-part-3-dynamic-placeholders.html